# file exception and cursor movement c++

Tags: c++, exception, ifstream, cursor-position

I use exception handling while reading from a file to determine if the part I wish to store in a variable is of the correct type (eg. I don't want to store a string in a double variable), but when the exception occurs, the cursor won't go to the next line. Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: With cursor, you mean the position in the file ?  Or the cursor on the screen ?

Comment: the position in the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [enabled exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) for incorrect/failed input, the first wrong character in the input stream will raise the exception.

If your error processing consist of skipping the rest of the line to resume with the procesing of the next line, you have to [clear](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) the error status  and then to [ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) the unread chars of the line.  Add the following in your exception processing code:

```
InputFile.clear(); // without this, every subsequent file op would fail 
InputFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

*You should however take care, because `>>` reading from streams might skip newlines as well, so that a missing data might position you already on the next line.  A safer approach would be to read the stream line by line with `std::getline()` and parse each line with a `stringstream`*.

Comment: It won't work. 

if(!(InputFile>> salary)){
            InputFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            throw myex;
        }

This is the code I am referring to...

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your code: and explain what makes you thnink that the code is lost ?

Comment: Sorry,  I realize tha ou didn't clear the error... I'll edit

Comment: Whenever I create an object (let's say test(myfile)) and in the file I have a string in the place where it should have been a double, it catches the exception, but so do all the following objects, even if the "arguments" that I read from the file are in the correct form.